# Netty4 and HTTP chunks

Tags: netty

I have a difficult time understanding how to use Chunks with Netty 4.

What I'm trying to do is to somehow replace a servlet keeping the connection opened and sending data twice per second.

So, I've looked at the headers returned by the servlet and now have a Netty handler extending `ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter<FullHttpRequest>`.

I'm actually doing something like this in my `messageReceived(...)` method:

```java
HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1,
                                                HttpResponseStatus.OK);
// initialize response
HttpHeaders headers = response.headers();
headers.set(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/event-stream");
headers.set(HttpHeaders.Names.CACHE_CONTROL,
            "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
headers.set(HttpHeaders.Names.PRAGMA, HttpHeaders.Values.NO_CACHE);
headers.set(HttpHeaders.Names.TRANSFER_ENCODING, HttpHeaders.Values.CHUNKED);
ctx.write(response);
```

I've added a `ChunkedWriteHandler` in my pipeline just before the above handler code.

Now, if I got this right, I'm now supposed to write `ChunkedInput`s in my channel in order to send *pieces* of data.

I've create a `ChunkedInput` subclass like this one:

```java
private class MyChunk implements ChunkedByteInput {
    private final ChannelHandlerContext ctx;
    private final String json;
    private boolean done = false;

    private HystrixChunk2(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String json) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.json = json;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean readChunk(ByteBuf buffer) throws Exception {
        buffer.writeBytes("data: ".getBytes())
                .writeBytes(json.getBytes())
                .writeBytes("\n".getBytes());
        done = true;
        LOGGER.info("Wrote chunck");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfInput() throws Exception {
        return done;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws Exception {
        ctx.channel().close();
    }
}
```

And basically in my `messageReceived(..)` method, I simply write some instance of that class.

But I may either have found a bug, or more likely don't understand how to use chunks with Netty, because nothing gets written on the output of my socket...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this problem I had was due to the fact that i sent a HTTP OK response instead of the 101-CONTINUE.

Seems to work fine now.